# xargs bash -c unexpected token

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

I'm experiencing an issue calling xargs inside a bash script to parallelize the launch of a function.

I have this line:

```
grep -Ev '^#|^$' "$listOfTables" | xargs -d '\n' -l1 -I args -P"$parallels" bash -c "doSqoop 'args'"
```

that launches the function `doSqoop` that I previously exported.
I am passing to `xargs` and then to `bash -c` a single, very long line, containing fields that I split and handle inside the function.
It is something like `schema|tab|dest|desttab|query|splits|....` that I read from a file, via the grep command above.  I am fine with this solution, I know xargs can split the line on `|` but I'm ok this way.

It used to work well since I had to add another field at the end, which contains this kind of value:

`field1='varchar(12)',field2='varchar(4)',field3='timestamp',....`

Now I have this error:
`bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

I tried to escape the pharhentesis and and single quotes, without success.
It appears to me that `bash -c` is interpreting the arguments

Comment: Why `xargs  .... bash -c "doSqoop 'args'"`? Isn't it the same as `xargs  .... doSqoop args`?

Comment: I need it to call a function that's contained in the script (which I exported), otherwise xargs would try to execute doSqoop as an external command.

Comment: Then it would be better to replace `xargs` with GNU parallel, that can work with exported functions.

Comment: At last I wasn't able to solve the issue. The problem was crearly related to bash interpreting the last field I added to the rows, so I ended up not adding that field. I am planning to convert the script to parallel, since xargs is not so easy to handle. Expecially about the mess it creates on video output. So, if you are in such a situation, directly go for paralell.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU parallel that can call exported functions, and also has an easier syntax and much more capabilities.

Your sample command should could be replaced with

```
grep -Ev '^#|^$' file | parallel doSqoop
```

Test with below script:

```
#!/bin/bash
doSqoop() {
  printf "%s\n" "$@"
}
export -f doSqoop
grep -Ev '^#|^$' file | parallel doSqoop
```

You can also set the number of processes with the `-P` option, otherwise it matches the number of cores in your system:

```
grep -Ev '^#|^$' file | parallel -P "$num" doSqoop
```

Comment: Spend an hour walking through `man parallel_tutorial`. Your command line will love you for it. `--colsep '\|'` may be of particular interest.